# C# - WebRequest fails on mono not in IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis, mono

It's my first post on SO

I am trying to parse an xml file from an extern server in C#. I use Visual Studio 2013 and IIS Express (default) to debug my code. My method works fine in IIS Express but my production Server use Debian 7 Apache 2 and Mono 3.2.0. It doesn't work on mono. This error appends :

```
Application Exception
System.FormatException
Invalid character at position 4

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.

Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): mscorlib.
Exception stack trace:
at System.Decimal.ThrowAtPos (int) [0x00000] in .../monobuild/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs:727
at System.Decimal.stripStyles (string,System.Globalization.NumberStyles,System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo,int&,bool&,bool&,int&,bool) [0x006c0] in .../monobuild/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs:991
at System.Decimal.PerformParse (string,System.Globalization.NumberStyles,System.IFormatProvider,System.Decimal&,bool) [0x00007] in .../monobuild/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs:1048
at System.Decimal.Parse (string,System.Globalization.NumberStyles,System.IFormatProvider) [0x0002d] in .../monobuild/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs:1019
at System.Decimal.Parse (string) [0x00000] in .../monobuild/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Decimal.cs:712
at System.Convert.ToDecimal (string) [0x0000d] in .../monobuild/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/Convert.cs:782
Version Information: 3.2.3 ((no/8d3b4b7 mardi 29 mars 2016, 17:49:21 (UTC+0200)); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.17020
Powered by Mono
```

Is it something wrong in the mono configuration ? because everything works fine with IIS even if the Request takes time (the XML file is big)

Thanks a lot

Comment: Exception is about problems with parsing decimal. Can you post here sample xml that is causing problems?

Comment: I am sorry I can't. I understand that my error is related with decimal but everything works fine on my programming environment which use IIS Express but it doesn't work on my test server which (as my production server) use Mono . Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: yea, it happens sometimes that things does not work the same way as on IIS when porting to mono, I've spent hours tweaking apps for mono. Please post here sample XML that causes problems so we can take a closer look what is going wrong. And also please provide the code that causes exception.